# Volume of Cone in Pyramid by Slicing/Integrating

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

This is my first time making a post on here but I am currently struggling with a problem.

I am unsure of how to proceed with this problem as I have only really worked with volumes of revolutions rotated about an axis.

However for this particular problem, I am asked to integrate areas by slicing a pyramid with it's top cut off with a cone bore through the middle.

I am thinking of integrating with respect to $y$, but I don't know how to begin. Any advice helps, thank you!

This is the specific shape of the object with dimensions in cm

[image]

Comment: I would also integrate with respect to y.  What is the area of the cross section?

Comment: No extra information was provided with the picture unfortunately, all I was given was this image and was told to find the area of each “slice” and integrate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $y$ denote the height above the base of a horizontal cross-section of the solid. Then we know that the area $A(y)$ of the cross-section at $y$ will have the form
\begin{equation}
A(y)=S^2(y)-\pi r^2(y)\tag{1}
\end{equation}

where $S(y)$ is the length of the side of the square at height $y$ and $r(y)$ the radius of the circle.

We see that both the length of the side of the square and the radius of the circle change linearly with $y$.

As $y$ increases from $0$ to $20$, $S$ decreases from $20$ to $10$ and $r$ increases from $0$ to $5$.

If you were to graph $S$ with respect to $y$ you would see that the graph of $S$ would be a straight line containing points $(0,20)$ and (20,10)$. Using the point-slope formula you learned in algebra you can see that

\begin{equation}
S(y)=20-\frac{1}{2}y
\end{equation}

Likewise, the graph of $r$ versus $y$ is a straight line containing the points $(0,0)$ and $(20,5)$ so $r$ has equation

\begin{equation}
r(y)=\frac{1}{4}y
\end{equation}

Using the fact that

$$ V=\int A(y)\,dy $$

and equation (1)

we get

$$ V=\int_0^{20}\left(20-\frac{1}{2}y\right)^2-\pi\left(\frac{1}{4}y\right)^2dy $$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

We have that

- the area of a slice for the pyramid with it's top cut off is

$$P(y)=\left(20-\frac{20+10}{20}y\right)^2$$

- the area of a slice for the cone is

$$C(z)=\pi \left(\frac{y}4\right)^2$$

then evaluate

$$V=\int_0^{20}(P(y)-C(y)) dy$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your input, one last question if you don’t mind. How did you come up with (y/4) as the radius for the cone in the area equation?

Comment: @brivic Because the radius varies linearl with y and at y=20 the radius is equal to 20/4=5.